# Australia Graduate Visa Post-Study Work stream study documents with credit exemption

Tags: visa, australia

I'm applying for a Graduate Visa in Australia (Post-Study Work stream). I understand that the study requirements is `2 years`.

**My education condition is as following:**

1. I studied master degree in 1.5 years (I got credit for a semester because of my bachelor degree)
2. I studied bachelor degree in 1 year

Both studies are in Australia.

**My question:**

When I apply for Graduate Visa Post-Study Work stream, do I need to include both my bachelor and master transcripts?

This is the website that includes the visa details: https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/temporary-graduate-485/post-study-work#HowTo

Comment: To answer your question to me on the previous version of this question, I thought it would cost more because you would have to pay for transcript copies from 2 programs, rather than 1.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @mkennedy! Fortunately I have the my bachelor transcript with me so I don't have to pay :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include only the bachelor's study, you will show you've done only 1 year of study. That's less than the 2 years required for the visa.

If you include only the master's, you will show only 1.5 years of study. That's also less than the 2 years required for the visa.

Thus, if you want to meet the visa requirement, you should include both courses of study. By including both, you'll show that you have studied for 2.5 years, which should satisfy the 2 year visa requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @David! So I just need to attach both transcripts, right?

Comment: If you want to show that you have studied for more than two years, then you should include both courses of study in your visa application.